# Maven Fails To Find Dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

This is a really odd error that I am getting while doing a maven build. I am encountering an error like this:

```
 a-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/multi-module-service/a-service/src/main/java/com/example/Controller.java: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method isNoneBlank(java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
```

At first, I thought it could be a bad dependency, so I checked that by adding the same dependency in another project. That builds fine. The next thing I checked was my maven version. The version our Jenkins uses is 3.6.0 and I was using 3.8.1. After switching to the Jenkins maven version, it still failed. Then I thought it could be an issue with having multiple versions. The mvn dependency:tree ruled that out though:

```
[INFO] com.example.service:a-service:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-security-sdk:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-2-adapter:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.keycloak:spring-boot-container-bundle:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-spi:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:9.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-persistence-sdk:jar:2020.11.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.8.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-model-sdk:jar:2020.11.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-search-sdk:jar:2020.11.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-storage-sdk:jar:2020.11.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.2-android:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.19:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.9.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.9.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:10.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:10.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.openfeign:feign-hystrix:jar:10.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-serialization:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.10.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-core:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-audit-sdk:jar:2020.11.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javers:javers-spring-boot-starter-sql:jar:5.10.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.javers:javers-spring-jpa:jar:5.10.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.javers:javers-spring:jar:5.10.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.javers:javers-core:jar:5.10.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:2.15:runtime
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.78:runtime
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javers:javers-persistence-sql:jar:5.10.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.polyjdbc:polyjdbc:jar:0.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-jobs-sdk:jar:2020.11.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.15:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.apps:internal-cache-sdk:jar:2020.22.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:jar:3.12.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.12.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:jar:3.12.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20190722:compile
[INFO] +- com.example.service:service-client:jar:2020.11.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] \- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:3.3:compile
```

At this point, I am really stuck. Does anyone have any insight into what could be causing this?

**Update 1**
Here is the code from the class where the StringUtils are being used:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/search/{a}/{b}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyResult> searchMyResultByAB(@PathVariable(value = "a") String a,@PathVariable(value="b")String b) throws ServiceException {
        if((StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)) && (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(b)){
            MyResult results = myResultService.searchResults(a,b);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(results);
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
    }
```

Also, here is my output from mvn -v:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T14:41:47-04:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\Documents\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_211, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Can you include the code around the `StringUrils.isNoneBlank(...)` call in your `Controller` class?

Comment: try force update dependencies with `mvn -U clean install`

Comment: I added where it is being used, and I have tried mvn -U clean install a few times. I have also tried deleting my local repo.

Comment: while declaring org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar, try excluding commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6

Comment: @AbhinavPandey, oddly enough that works. Why would Maven be confusing the two dependencies though? The import in the class is import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils. Also, none of my other colleagues are running into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really silly about this now. It turns out someone uploaded something to our internal artifactory for commons-lang that was not really commons-lang. No idea how that happened, but it was a never-ending source of frustration for me. If anyone else ever sees something that doesn't make sense like this, compare the size of the jar in your .m2 folder with one downloaded directly from maven central. That would have saved me a lot of time.